# How to get this JSON format value in android?

Tags: android, android-json

How can I create a JSON with this format in Android?

I want to send this JSON in my SOAP Web Service Parameter

```
"{'\obj\':{\"MeterSrNo\":\"5\"},'\SPName\':'XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail'}"
```

SPName is my second parameter.

Comment: why you have MeterSrNo in " " ?

Comment: Its a unique id number. when user type his unique number in editText then  all his detail fill in all textview.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
     obj.put("MeterSrNo", "5");
     jsonObject.put("obj", obj);
     jsonObject.put("SPName", "XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail");
} catch (JSONException e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Cherry Perry. You have given same what i mentioned in my question But this format not helped me. Now i want serialized method like below-

"{'\obj\':{\"MeterSrNo\":\"5\"},'\SPName\':'XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail'}"

Comment: Well, in this case this is not json at all. Construct your string via String.format.

Comment: I implement this but its not formatted what i want. will you please provide a example ?

Comment: String.format("{'\\obj\\':{\\\"MeterSrNo\\\":\\\"%d\\\"},'\\SPName\\':'%s'}", 5, "XXMFU_GETMobilityDetail")?